# Aiomas RPC Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, rpc, python-asyncio

My goal is to bind TCP RPC server aiomas and clients in different programming languages.
I'm setting the connection, but neither the response from the server nor the response is received.
The documentation says:

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/aiomas/1.0.3/aiomas.pdf

```
 Page 26: - On the RPC level, it a three-tuple:
[function, [arg0, arg1, ...], {kwarg0: val0, kwarg1: val1}]
function is a string containing the name of an exposed functions; The type of the arguments and keyword arguments may vary depending on the function.
```

This simple server:

```
import aiomas

class Server:
    router = aiomas.rpc.Service()

    @aiomas.expose
    def ping(self, i):
        print('Ping receive data: {}'.format(i))
        return i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = aiomas.run(aiomas.rpc.start_server(
        ('127.0.0.1', 5000),
        Server())
    )
    print('Server run')
    aiomas.run(server.wait_closed())
```

And this my problem tcp client

```
import socket
import pickle


MESS = ['ping', [1]]

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5000))
s.settimeout(1.5)
s.send(pickle.dumps(MESS))
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

Tell me please what's wrong. It is necessary to understand in order to realize this in other languages.Much grateful for any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the documentation several times, But I did not understand how to compose the header of the package. As a result, I figured out that the last byte is the length of the package. Everything worked.
Here is an example package

```
data='[0, 0, ["methood", ["args"], {"kwargs":"if exists"}]]'

hex(len(data)) -->  0x35

b'\x00\x00\x00\x35[0, 0, ["methood", ["args"], {"kwargs":"if exists"}]]'
```